# Flask Security to API without db at backend

Tags: flask

I am new to Stack overflow. I developed an API using Flask but I want to add security to it so that only those who has some key can run it. No database at backend, any token based or other latest secure way of running the API? 
For eg: app.route('/test') if I run it using local_host/test then it triggered, the same way no one from the team who has the same access should not run that easily until and unless I(Producer) provide some key to Consumer and Consumer uses that key to connect my API.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with basic authentication. This means that every time someone makes a request to your endpoint, they need to supply a username and password in the header with the request.

A great minimal example is located here: https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```py
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    if username == 'approved_username' and password == 'correct-password':
        return True
    return False

@app.route('/')
@auth.login_required
def index():
    return "Hello, %s!" % auth.username()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I've modified it slightly to make it even more simple by removing the dynamic user lookup.

To use this, you just need to add the `auth.login_required` decorator to any route you wish to protect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the above solution is prompting me to username and pwd, any other solution where we can read username and pwd from some config file, please?

Comment: If you try to access that route from a browser it will ask you for a username and password, but API's are not typically accessed from a browser. When you access the API using python, curl, JS, etc... you pass the base 64 encoded 'username:password' string along with the request and there will be no need to enter anything into a prompt.

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, it worked!! Need one more help.. how to run this API 24/7(even when system restarts, it should run once the system/server is on). Using Waitress as web server in windows server, when I run with python test.py it runs on command prompt which will get closed whn system gets restarted.... Need permanent solution in Windows please